# Laravel Resource Controller producing 404 despite being properly routed

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have created a resource controller called `BirdsController`. The controllers index and show methods route to pages correctly. But the create method is producing 404 error despite the route and controller being properly set up. What produces this error?

web.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\BirdsController;


Route::get('wildlife/birds', [BirdsController::class, 'index'])->name('birds');
Route::get('wildlife/birds/{bird:name}', [BirdsController::class, 'show'])->name('birds.show');
Route::get('wildlife/birds/create', [BirdsController::class, 'create'])->name('birds.create');
```

BirdsController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Birds;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BirdsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $birds = Birds::all();
        return view('wildlife.birds.index',compact('birds'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('wildlife.birds.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Birds  $birds
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Birds $bird)
    {
        return view('wildlife.birds.show', compact('bird'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution after modifying the route 'create' from;

```
Route::get('wildlife/birds/create', [BirdsController::class, 'create'])->name('birds.create');
```

to;

```
Route::get('wildlife/bird/create', [BirdsController::class, 'create'])->name('birds.create');
```

replaced the plural 'birds' to 'bird' only in create method and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use the Controller as resource in web.php route file?

```
Route::group('prefix' => 'wildlife', function() {

    Route::resource('birds',BirdsController::class);

});
```

Comment: I avoided using the resource route because later in the development process I want to make the index and show methods of the same controller accessible to all users, while restricting create, edit, store and update methods accessible only to site  admin and editors.